# what should be the way to pass multiple activerecord object from controller to views?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I will give an example.

Say I have Category and Product as my two models and another ChosenProduct that specifies/handles the many to many relationship between them. Now when I have certain categories and I am iterating in a loop on these categories getting the corresponding products. How to access these multiple product objects in my view?

I am new to Rails and MVC so for now I am doing this task in my view itself. But I think this shouldn't be the right way. How should I approach this ?

I am adding my view code as asked. This works for me fine now. But I don't think its pretty.

```
    <ul>
    <% @categories.each do |category| %>
    <li>
    <%= image_submit_tag("add.png", :height => "20", :width => '20', :name=>"add_product_to_#{category.id}", :id=>"add_product_to_#{category.id}" ) %>

    <%= category.category_name %>
    <% @chosen_products = category.chosen_products %>
    <% @chosen_products.each do |chosen_product| %>
        <% @products = Product.where(:id => chosen_product.product_id).all %>
        <% @products.each do |product| %>
            <ul>
                <li><%= product.product_name %>
                    <ul>
                        <li><%= image_tag("#{product.product_image_url}", :size => "200x200", :alt => "Can not load image!") %></li>
                        <li><%= product.product_image_url %></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        <% end %>
    <% end %>
<% end %>
</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: add you view code and we'll see how we can improve it :)

Comment: Marshal your data in the controller and let the view code do all the iterating necessary. Ideally (and this is a matter of opinion, you will find proponents on both sides), your view code does not do any database reading. I.e., no  Product.find() or Product.where(). If you find yourself itching to make those sorts of calls, you probably  want an ajax solution.

Answer (score 0):

To iterate over a collection of objects of the same class, you must use a partial, it will iterate over your collection for you. Suppose this:

```
#controller
def index
 @categories = Category.all
end
```

Then you will need a partial view called `_category.html.erb` in your views/categories/ with the logic of your view. Lets suppose your partial is:

```
    <div class="info">
       <p class="name"><%= category.name %></p>
</div>
```

The partial will receive a collection of categories, and it will iterate over the collection automatically. So in the partial you must call the object in the singular form, in this case `category` to refer the actual object that is being rendered.

Then in your `index.html.erb` view, all you need is to render the partial.

```
<%= render @categories %>
```

or

```
<%= render(partial: "categories/category", collection: @categories) || "<h1>There are no categories</h1>".html_safe %>
```

The second option will render what is next to `||` in case the collection `@categories` is empty.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you have defined the associations between models as

app/models/chosen_product.rb

```
class ChosenProduct < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :category
  belongs_to :product
end
```

app/models/category.rb

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :chosen_products
  has_many :products, through: :chosen_products
end
```

So in your your view you could do

```
<ul>
  <% @categories.each do |category| %>
  <li>
    <%= image_submit_tag("add.png", :height => "20", :width => '20', :name=>"add_product_to_#{category.id}", :id=>"add_product_to_#{category.id}" ) %>

    <%= category.category_name %>
    <% category.products.each do |product| %>
      <ul>
         <li><%= product.product_name %>
            <ul>
               <li><%= image_tag("#{product.product_image_url}", :size => "200x200", :alt => "Can not load image!") %></li>
               <li><%= product.product_image_url %></li>
            </ul>
         </li>
      </ul>
    <% end %>
 </li>
<% end %>
```